# Transfer S3 bucket contents from one account to other account in different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to transfer the S3 bucket contents using the AWS CLI from

```
AWS account A -> Tokyo region (ap-northeast-1) -> S3 bucket -> account1bucket
```

To

```
AWS account B -> N.Virginia region (us-east-1) -> S3 bucket -> account2bucket
```

Followed the steps from https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-s3/ by creating the exact bucket policies,IAM policy and executed the following command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://account1bucket s3://account2bucket
```

That’s giving me the following error :

[image: I have tried using the tools like S3] object explorer, bucket explorer using Access ID/Secret Key and able to successfully connect to `AWS account A` but not `AWS account B`. The only difference i could see is MFA is enabled on `AWS account B`.Technically this shouldn't be a problem as i am able to publish contents to `AWS account B` S3 buckets from Jenkins using Access ID/Secret Key successfully.

Following are the policy's i have defined at the Source bucket level and the destination user acconut level:

AWS account A S3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "delegates3access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWSAccountB:user/user@user.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::account1bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::account1bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

AWS account B user policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::account1bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::account1bucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::account2bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::account2bucket/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If the source and destination regions are different then you need to explicitly indicate the source region with the --source-region parameter.

Comment: yes i have tried that too: aws s3 sync s3://account1bucket s3://account2bucket --source-region ap-northeast-1, still the same error. any thing wrong in my command ?

Comment: IAM users are specified in policies as arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name.

Comment: You will need one IAM User (User B?) that can read Bucket A and write to Bucket B. Once you have those credentials correct, the `aws s3 sync` command should work. Please note that permissions can only be granted by the account that 'owns' the bucket, so the User B policy you have shown cannot grant access to `account1bucket`. The Account A Bucket Policy looks generally correct, but it sounds like it is not working, so keep working on fixing that policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the AWS destination account credentials, used the AWS source account credentials and it worked with the following command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://account1bucket s3://account2bucket --source-region ap-northeast-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this excellent blog post about *S3* replication across regions https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/